# Initiate instance variables at the time of their iteration

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Lets say we have a loop in our controller, that's going through an array of numbers, checking whether they're even or odd:

```
[1,2,3,4,5].each do |number|
  if number.odd?
    @odd_count += 1
  else
    @even_count += 1
  end
end
```

My question is if there's a way to do this array *without* previously setting the @odd_count and @even_count variables? If you execute the previous code block in a controller, you get

```
undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass
```

but I do not really want to do

```
@odd_count = 0
@even_count = 0
```

before the loop, because it's extra lines of code that don't look nice. For the sake of the question, let's say we have 10 different things we want to count, not 2.

Comment: Are you sure instance variables are really what you want?

Comment: Well, yes, I want to know the answer to this theoretical situation. One way to work around this is to use a hash, which then only has to be initialised once..

Comment: You could use `@odd_count = @odd_count.to_i.succ` instead of `@odd_count += 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@odd_count = (@odd_count || 0) + 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, if I understand you correctly, replace:

```
@odd_count += 1
```

with:

```
@odd_count = @odd_count.to_i.next
```

Comment: This doesn't really work if we have 10 variables we want to set instead of two.

Comment: If you have a lot of instance variables like that why don't you use a hash? What are the names of the variables? `@divisible_by_2_count`, `@divisible_by_3_count`, `@divisible_by_4_count`...?

Comment: Yes, hash is an option, but I want to know whether there's a possibility to initialise the instance variable at the time of assigning a value to it. That's the question.

Comment: @test, it will. `nil.to_i # => 0`.

Comment: @test, I did... and it worked. What do you get and what version of Ruby are you using?

Comment: I tried this in IRB using jruby 1.7.18, MRI 2.2.2, MRI 1.9.3 - all worked just fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
odd = a.select {|n| n % 2 != 0}.inject(0) {|acc, n| acc + 1}
even = a.length - odd
```